# Configuring actor behavior using typesafe Config and HOCON

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, hocon

I am building a large agent-based / multi-agent model of a stock exchange using Akka/Play/Scala, etc and I am struggling a bit to understand how to configure my application. Below is a snippet of code that illustrates an example of the type of problem I face:

```
class Exchange extends Actor {

  val orderRoutingLogic = new OrderRoutingLogic()

  val router = {

    val marketsForSecurities = securities.foreach { security =>

      val marketForSecurity = context.actorOf(Props[DoubleAuctionMarket](
        new DoubleAuctionMarket(security) with BasicMatchingEngine), security.name
      )
      orderRoutingLogic.addMarket(security, marketForSecurity)

    }
    Router(orderRoutingLogic)

  }
```

In the snippet above I inject a `BasicMatchingEngine` into the `DoubleAuctionMarket`. However I have written a number of different matching engines and I would like to be able to configure the type of matching engine injected into `DoubleAuctionMarket` in the application configuration file.

Can this level of application configuration be done using typesafe Config and HOCON configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting case. If I understood you right, you want to configure `Market` actor mixing in some `MatchingEngine` type specified in config?

Some clarification: you can't simply mix in dynamic type. I mean if you move `MatchingEngine` type to config - it will be known only at runtime, when config is parsed. And at that time you'll not be able to instantiate `new DoubleAuctionMarket(security) with ???SomeClassInstance???`. But maybe you could replace inheritance with aggregation. Maybe an instance of `MatchingEngine` can be passed to Market as parameter?

Now, how to obtain an instance of `MatchingEngine` from config? In short - Typesafe Config has no parser for [FQCN](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Fully_Qualified-Class-Name-(Java)-(FQCN).html) properties, but it's not hard to do it yourself using reflection. This technique is used in many places in Akka. Look [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L75) first. `provider` property set as fqcn string and can be changed to other provider (i.e. `RemoteActorRefProvider`) in other configurations. Now look at how it's processed to obtain `Provider` instance. First it's just being read as string [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L171). Then `ProviderClass` is used to instantiate actual (runtime) provider [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L617). [`DynamicAccess`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/DynamicAccess.scala#L63) is a utility helping with reflexive calls. It's not publicly accessible via context.system, but just take a piece of it or instantiate yourself, I don't think it's a big issue.

With some modifications, your code may look:

```
class Exchange extends Actor {

  val orderRoutingLogic = new OrderRoutingLogic()
  val matchingEngineClass = context.system.settings.config.getString("stocks.matching-engine")
  val matchingEngine = DynamicAccess.createInstance[MatchingEngine](matchingEngineClass)

  val router = {

    val marketsForSecurities = securities.foreach { security =>

      val marketForSecurity = context.actorOf(DoubleAuctionMarket.props(security, matchingEngine))
      orderRoutingLogic.addMarket(security, marketForSecurity)

    }
    Router(orderRoutingLogic)

  }
```

I've moved props to companion object of DoubleAuctionMarket as stated in Recommended Preactices of [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/scala/actors.html#Recommended_Practices). Usage of `Props(new Actor())` is dangerous practice.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem very close to what I want to do. It may be that my question is somewhat ill-posed: what I want may fall under the heading of "how to manage dependency injection for a big model/application?"  It seems like there are libraries (i.e., Guice, Spring, and Play) that can help with this. Your answer also seems like a step in that direction.  I will have a think about it and get back to you.